# How to add activity indicator to image load

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to add activity indicator to image load on image view. How it possible please help, Thank You

## My code

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
NSError *error;

NSLog(@"Error in receiving data %@",error);
NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&error];
NSLog(@"response data %@",json);

NSArray* results = [json objectForKey:@"status"];
NSArray *imageUrlArray = [results valueForKey:@"slider_image_path"];
NSLog(@"images %@",imageUrlArray);

NSMutableArray *arrayImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSString *strImageUrl in imageUrlArray) {
    [arrayImages addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImageUrl]]]];
}


self.imageview.animationImages = arrayImages;
_imageview.animationDuration = 10;
_imageview.animationRepeatCount = 0;
[_imageview startAnimating];


}
```

Comment: seems in delegate connectionDidFinishLoading you should stop the indicator. Start - in another delegate. Or in other manner: start - before async data fetching task, stop - in closure of such task.

Comment: @drewpts How it possible please explain

Comment: @sm5345 already explained the idea. The main idea is to stop indicator in async request. Hence you do not know when exactly async task will be performed - you need to put stop command not after async task but exactly in it: see the ```[indicator removeFromSuperview]``` in objc block? Btw please read what is blocks in objc or closures in swift and their role in async tasks if you do not know that stuff yet. Peace.

Comment: if you are using storyboard or Code way?

Comment: @IyyappanRavi I used a storyboard

Comment: set the activity indicator inside the imageview, if image is load show indicator, then image is loaded its automatically hide activity indicator, its storyboard process. try this

Comment: @AnkurKumawat check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do like following :

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *indctr = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[indctr startAnimating];
[indctr setCenter:self.imageView.center];
[self.contentView addSubview:indctr];
```

Comment: This method only add UI but i want a image load start indicator after load stop indicator

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[indicator startAnimating];
[indicator setCenter:self.imageView.center];
[self.contentView addSubview:indicator];
```

Remove the indicator from the superview in the block's succes method.

```
[_imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:anURL]
                   success:^(UIImage *image) {
                       [indicator removeFromSuperview];
                   }
                   failure:^(NSError *error) {

                   }];
```

}

Comment: for (NSString *strImageUrl in imageUrlArray) { UIImageView * imageView=[[UIImage alloc]init]; UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
[indicator startAnimating];
[indicator setCenter:self.imageView.center];
[self.contentView addSubview:indicator];[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL: strImageUrl]
                   success:^(UIImage *image) {
                       [indicator removeFromSuperview];
                   }failure:^(NSError *error) {
         }];  [arrayImages addObject:imageView]; }

Comment: replace for loop by this

Answer (score 0):

You Can use the MBProgress HUD class:https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD
download it and in your code set this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
MBProgressHUD *HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc]initWithView:self.view];
        [self.view addSubview:HUD];
}
    -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
    NSError *error;

    NSLog(@"Error in receiving data %@",error);
    [HUD show: YES];
    NSMutableDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&error];
    NSLog(@"response data %@",json);

    NSArray* results = [json objectForKey:@"status"];
    NSArray *imageUrlArray = [results valueForKey:@"slider_image_path"];
    NSLog(@"images %@",imageUrlArray);

    NSMutableArray *arrayImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSString *strImageUrl in imageUrlArray) {
        [arrayImages addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strImageUrl]]]];
    }


    self.imageview.animationImages = arrayImages;
    _imageview.animationDuration = 10;
    _imageview.animationRepeatCount = 0;
    [_imageview startAnimating];

    [HUD hide: YES];
    }
```

Comment: import MB progress HUD but HUD undeclared identifier